# C# Method to take list of types with same property

Tags: c#, list

I have a few different types all with a common property:

```
public class A {
  public int SomeCommonProperty { get; set; }

   /*
    * some other stuff
    */
}

public class B {
  public int SomeCommonProperty { get; set; }

  /*
   * some other stuff
   */
}
```

I want to have a method that takes a list of any of these objects with this property so that I can iterate through the list and compare that property with another parameter like:

```
public static List<T> MethodToTakeListOfAboveTypes<T>(this List<T> destinationList, List<T> sourceList, string someProp)
{
  if (sourceList != null && sourceList.Exists(tab => tab.SomeCommonProperty  == someProp))
  {
    destinationList = sourceList.Where(tab => tab.SomeCommonProperty == someProp).ToList();
  }
  return destinationList;
}
```

The above code does not work as T does not have a definition of "SomeCommonProperty", which makes sense.
I want to simply pass a more generic object with that property so that I dont have to create this same method for each type. I just cannot get the syntax right. Does this make sense?

I know I should put the SomeCommonProperty field in to a base class and inherit, but that doesn't seem to work either for some reason.

Comment: Inheritance is specifically designed to handle this situation. Why do you think it “doesn't seem to work”?

Answer (score 4):

Make all your classes implement some interface (or inherit this property from some base class), e.g.

```
public interface ICommonInterface
{
   int SomeCommonProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can put interface/class constraint on generic parameter type:

```
public static List<T> MethodToTakeListOfAboveTypes<T>(          
   this List<T> destinationList, List<T> sourceList, string someProp)
    where T: ICommonInterface
{
   // ...
}
```

NOTE: You can avoid checking if any item with someProp exist in source (in worst case you will have to enumerate sourceList twice). Simply do filtering and check if there are any results

```
public static List<T> MethodToTakeListOfAboveTypes<T>(
     this List<T> destinationList, List<T> sourceList, string someProp)
     where T: ICommonInterface
{
    if (sourceList == null)
        return destinationList;

    var filtered = sourceList.Where(s => s.SomeCommonProperty == someProp).ToList();
    return filtered.Any() ? filtered : destinationList;
}
```

Comment: It's probably a better approach to use inheritance rather than an interface + extension method in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> I know I should put the SomeCommonProperty field in to a base class and inherit, but that doesn't seem to work either for some reason.

You need to add a generic constraint then it will work just fine

```
where T : CommonType
```

Answer (score 1):

If the base class contains a property with that name, the only thing you have to do is tell the generic method that the type must inherit from that base class:

```
public static List<T> MethodToTakeListOfAboveTypes<T>(this List<T> destinationList, List<T> sourceList, string someProp) where T : BaseClass
```

Note the use of `where T :` which actually says `T` has to derive from ...

Replace `BaseClass` with your actual base class name.

```
public class BaseClass
{
   public string SomeCommonProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface with that property that each class implements, then add a constraint to your generic method:

```
public interface ICommonProperty
{
    int SomeCommonProperty {get;set;}
}

public class A : ICommonProperty
{
    public int SomeCommonProperty { get; set; }
}

public class B : ICommonProperty
{
    public int SomeCommonProperty { get; set; }
}

public static List<T> MethodToTakeListOfAboveTypes<T>(this List<T> destinationList, List<T> sourceList, string someProp) where T : ICommonProperty
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can go with inheritance (as you say you can), you should do that. However, if for some reason you need to iterate through a bunch of objects that you don't have the source for and access some property you know they have, you can use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx):

```
class foo
{
    public string myProp = "foo";
}

class bar
{
    public string myProp = "bar";
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
        list.Add(new foo());
        list.Add(new bar());

        foreach (dynamic o in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o.myProp);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also call arbitrary methods on a `dynamic`. You get an exception if the property / method doesn't exist.